# How to fix a AttributeError in Python?

Tags: python

I don't success to fix this error on my code. Python wrote me this error message:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chloé CHAUMETON\Documents\BioAxial\1_R&D\4_Software\2_Python\Measurement_script\Matlab_to_Python\2019\Chloe_script_V3.py", line 114, in <module>
    if 0 < len((lrir)(lrir.name_file)):
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name_file' "
```

I defined the `"name_file = 'BSR_Main.exe2018_09_14.csv' "` up of my code but I don't understand why python don't attribute this name fto the function. Here is my code.

```
i_r=[]

def lrir():

lrir = liste_record[i_r]

name_file = 'BSR_Main.exe2018_09_14.csv';

for i_r in range(0,rec-1):

    if 0 < len((lrir)(lrir.name_file)):

        str1 = ligne.find(lrir.name_file,'/')
        pr_rep = os.path.join(dir_PR,s(i_r).name_file)
        log_rep = os.path.join(pr_rep,'Log')
        log_file = glob.glob(os.path.join(log_rep,'*.log'))
        print('log file:',log_file)
```

Comment: `pr_rep = os.path.join(dir_PR,s(i_r),name_file)` instead of `pr_rep = os.path.join(dir_PR,s(i_r).name_file)` Notice the `,`

Comment: i changed the , but the problme came above the code. At this line :

 if 0 < len((lrir)(lrir.name_file)):

Comment: `name_file` is not an attribute of `lrir()` so `lrir.name_file` is invalid

Comment: Multiple variables in your code are not defined. Please read the Help Center article on [creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)